# Check if default webbrowser has domain open

Tags: c#, browser

I'm looking for a way to check if the default browser has a tab open to a specific domain address. And if it is i like to change the URL on this tab instead of open a new tab like I'm doing right now with this code.

```
Process.Start(URL);
```

Is this even possible with general solution. To be clear I don't want to do this in IE only and i would prefer not implementing one solution for every browser.

Edit: I have a program that will open a webpage from the program. And What I want to do is to open this page only if it's not open already if it is open i just want to redirect it to an other place on the website. I hope this made it clearer.

Comment: To be able to read all current addresses from all tabs in a browser and even being able to change the current address of a given tab is a huge security concern. How would you see this happen? Imagine this would be possible, wouldn't there be tons of malware redirecting `https://yourbank.com` to `https://fakepagethattotallylookslikeyourbank.com`? Please explain the problem you're trying to solve. Wouldn't a Windows domain policy that sets a certain start page (yeah, IE only) work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In plain html, instead of using `<a href="page.html" target="_blank">link</a>`, you can use a named target (`target="myWindow"`) to reuse the same window (or tab).

I'm not sure if it is possible to specify a window-name in that `Process.Start`, but could you use a small extra html file in the 'Process.Start' that a) opens the real URL in a named window; b) closes the window that was used for this small file?